# Specifying initial volatility term while simulating GARCH model in R

Tags: r, simulation, forecasting, quantitative-finance

So I simulated a GARCH (APARCH) model in R using GarchFit and did a simulation  for weekly log returns:

On specifying different values of h0 (initial volatility), I get different predictions for my data, and the accuracy is converging and good for h0=2.2e-4.

This is of course obtained by iterations by me. I want to know the procedure, of how to subsitute an appropriate value of h0 (initial volatility) in the code below, or a better way to calibrate h0 using data. (as different h0 results in different fits to the model, without having to manually find out the best h0 by repeatedly substituting different values and looking for a good fit, is there another efficient way to find an h0 that returns 'best fit'?

Here is the simulation code:

```
`randhelp <- function(
 horizon,
 N,
 h0,  
 mu,
 omega,
 alpha1 , 
 gamma1,beta1,delt

 )
 {
rett<-zt <- et <- ht <- matrix(NA, nc=horizon, nr=N) #matrices to store #simulated values of various parameters

ht[,1] <- h0
for(j in 1:horizon){
zt[,j]   <- rsstd(N,mean=0.01076,sd=1.01309,nu=6.80980352,xi=0.99555) 
#innovation
et[,j]   <- zt[,j]*sqrt(ht[,j]) #et is the return, same as rett here
rett[,j]  <- et[,j]+omega+mu #omega and mu don't matter and are to be given 
#the values zero


 if( j < horizon ){
 ht[,j+1]<- (alpha1*(abs(et[,j])-gamma1*et[,j])^(delt) + beta1*
 (ht[,j])^(delt/2))^(2/delt)}}
 rett #final matrix of simulated values for each step in the horizon
 }`
```

Comment: Please include your code or the part that you have a question about

Comment: @MrFlick  please note the edited code and the problem statement. I hope I got it right.

Comment: @codeforester please note the edited code and problem statement.

Comment: How do I re-submit the question to actually make this post active? I already edited it 8 hours ago @Ibo

Comment: read this page and post a better question. That will increase your chance of getting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask